# Partial refactoring to Spring

Tags: spring, servlets, refactoring

I'm working on a pretty old application that I would like to migrate to Spring.
Since it's quite big and there are a lot of people currently using it, I wanted to start migrating only the new functionalities or the code I happen to touch (e.g. for bug fixing).

So my question is, can classic javax servlet and Spring Controllers coexist in the same app?

Please no comments on how to do proper refactoring. This is the only option I have to improve the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can have application with regular Servlets among Spring and among other framework as guice.

You can in parallel get request using Spring controllers which will execute Spring's Services and Repositories without interrupting your old servlets.

Spring is built on top of java so can use regular java methods (for re-usability)

Also your classic Servlet can gradually auto-wire spring framework when you will be ready

Comment: I would I add Spring to an existing application? All the examples I've seen start from a basic Spring app.

Comment: @algiogia it can/was done for legacy application, if you want you can build a new module/jar that will be spring/spring-boot

Comment: Are you suggesting to deploy the old app and a new Spring Boot app separately? I was interested in adding Spring to the current app and slowly replace the existing components

Comment: @algiogia You can add it to existing app